# How to get Last Modified Timestamp of a file from sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a Web Application in ASP.NET wherein I need to find out Last Modified Timestamp  of a file (the path of file is given).

But, I could not figure out How to do It.
I have written below code

```
String getTimestamp(String pathLink)
{

    String retVal = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pathLink);
        request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
        request.Proxy = null;

        using (FtpWebResponse resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            retVal= resp.LastModified.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle Appropriately
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

but is throwing exception:

```
{System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (501) Not Implemented.
```

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()...

Microsoft also says same thing [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.FtpWebRequest.aspx)

```
UseDefaultCredentials =>Always throws a NotSupportedException. (Overrides WebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials.)
```

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't such a thing as "default credentials", at least not something that has information which can actually be used to access pages such as username/password info. If this is something which isn't being accessed directly by end users, you can pass in specific credentials like so:

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

request.Credentials = credentials;
```

If you want end users accessing this and only getting information that they're authorized to get in SharePoint, that's going to be a bit harder. Windows credentials are going to be hidden from you, and for good reason: you don't want people to be able to write a few lines of code and access all of that info. In order to unhide them, you could set up your site for Kerberos and then use that to pass information along. I *believe* that only the side sending credentials needs to have Kerberos set up, but I could be wrong about that...